# Excel function for calculating total spent time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have an excel sheet, where in some columns I have cells of the type `integer,integerM` or `integer,integerH`, for instance `1,30m` or `5,2H`. For all the column I would like to get an expression that checks for each column cell if there is `H` (hours) or `m` (minutes) in the second integer, and in that case calculates the total number of hours (float value) for all those second integers in the column.

For instance, if we have one column with four cells:

```
1,30m
5,2H
3,20m
4,1H
```

The total sum would be:

```
30m + 2H + 20m + 1H = 0.5 + 2 + 0.33333 + 1 = 3.83333 H
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you need the cells you have to stay in this format?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your first cell is A2 and you can put calculations in any of the columns to the right of it.

- B2: `=MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1,99)` (finds the stuff after the comma)
- C2: `=VALUE(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1))` (extracts the number before the 'h' or 'm')
- D2: `=LOWER(RIGHT(B2,1))` (extracts the 'h' or 'm') (although you don't need `LOWER` - see Scott's comment)
- E2: `=IF(D2="m",C2/60,IF(D2="h",C2,""))` (calculates the number of hours)

Then you can sum column E.

You could put this in one cell and have a long formula, but this is easier to debug and saves repeating yourself in a formula.

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me, could you just give an example of a column where this works for you?

Comment: Which bit isn't working?

Comment: Your answer seems to work fine, but you can simplify it a bit by removing the `LOWER()` -- text comparison in Excel is case-insensitive unless you use `EXACT()`.

Comment: Ah - I didn't realise that - thanks! I'd never heard of `EXACT()`. Every day's a schoolday :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by benshepherd is good, +1 from me. If you were looking to change the data setup, I thought I'd leave another answer that may be useful for someone somewhere.

- First, I'd do *text to columns* in the *data* tab, delimited with the `,`
- Next, I'd align the cells to the right with the `h` and `m` and do another *text to columns* with a fixed width, pulling the non-numeric characters to the next cell.
- Then, in the fourth column, I could use a formula like `=IF(C1="h",B1,IF(C1="m",B1/60,0))` and sum that column